# How to take values from a dictionary into my own dictionary properly

Tags: python

I need to create a dictionary whose keys are unique course codes and whose values are dictionaries with a single key-value pair describing the sections available for that course code, in alphabetical order, as well as the ID numbers that belong to the specific section, in ascending order.

The data is from a dictionary called student_data that looks like this:

```
student_data[:3]

>>>[{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}], 
'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}], 
'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'}, 
{'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}], 
'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]
```

Format of the desired output:

```
{
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My code at the moment looks like this but it keeps throwing a Key Error.

```
class_lists = {}

for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if i['id'] not in class_lists:
            class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']] = {'sections':[j['section']],'class list':[i['id']]}
        else:
            if j['section'] not in class_lists[j['course code']]['sections']:
                class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']].append(i['id'])
    
print(class_lists)
```

```
>>> KeyError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-b49d236b3190> in <module>
     11 
     12             if j['section'] not in class_lists:
---> 13                 class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']] = {'class list':[i['id']]}
     14             else:
     15                 class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']].append(i['id'])

KeyError: 'UK 60'
```

Comment: Post the exact error it gives you. KeyError at which line?

Comment: Edited my post to include the error. Thank you!

Comment: why is the line different in the traceback than in the code?

Comment: Your desired dictionary has a duplicated key course_code.
Maybe you want an array of dictionaries instead of a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class_list = {}
for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in class_list.keys():
            # if course code not exist
            class_list[j['course code']] = {} # Declare initially
            class_list[j['course code']][j['section']] = {"sections":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]}
        else:
            if j['section'] in class_list[j['course code']].keys():
                # if course id & section already available push i['id']
                class_list[j['course code']][j['section']]['class list'].append(i['id'])
            else:
                class_list[j['course code']][j['section']] = {"sections":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]}
```

The error was you have to declare `class_list[j['course code']] = {} before adding values to class_list[j['course code']][j['section']]` to program understand that you are adding dictionary to the `class_list[j['course code']]` instead of a value

**EDIT**

To get the desired output format

```
class_list = {}
class_sections = {}
for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in class_list.keys():
            class_list[j['course code']] = [{"sections":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]}]
            class_sections[j['course code']] = [j['section']]
        else:
            if j['section'] in class_sections[j['course code']]:
                index_ = class_sections[j['course code']].index(j['section'])
                class_list[j['course code']][index_]['class list'].append(i['id'])
            else:
                class_list[j['course code']].append({"sections":j['section'],'class list':[i['id']]})
                class_sections[j['course code']].append(j['section'])
```

Comment: Can I ask how can I modify this so that the section letter doesn't appear before the 'section':"A" part?

Comment: You have to make class_list[j['course code']] to a list and appect new sections to the list but you have to do little more validation when appending id_number to the `class_list`

Comment: What kind of validation do I have to add to append the id_number to the corresponding sections?

Comment: Let say one course have multiple sections and you have to append one id_number to class list, you have to know row number of section in the `class_lists[j['course code']]` to append id_number. I will update accrodingly

Answer (score 0):

You declared an empty dictionary:

```
class_lists = {}  # Is an empty dictionary
```

Then you wrote this:

```
class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']] = ...
```

For the first loop, it will translate to:

```
class_lists["UK 60"]["A"] = ...
```

Which means that you are are already accessing `class_lists["UK 60"]` and treating its value as a dict by accessing [**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) via the call to `["A"]` even though the dict doesn't exist yet. Basically, you are already expecting `class_lists` to be:

```
class_lists = {
    "UK 60": {}
}
```

When at that moment, it was only this:

```
class_lists = {}
```

Note that there is a difference in dict between assignment operation and accessing the value as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> d[key]
>
> Return the item of d with key key. Raises a **KeyError** if key is not in the map.
>
> d[key] = value
>
> Set d[key] to value.

### Solution

To solve this, I changed first:

```
if i['id'] not in class_lists:
```

To:

```
if j['course code'] not in class_lists:
```

Because based on your logic, your `class_lists` hold keys by course code, not by id.

### Alternative 1:

Manually assign an empty dict to the course code before assigning the section. You can also use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for this purpose.

```
if j['course code'] not in class_lists:
    class_lists[j['course code']] = {}  # Or dict.setdefault
    class_lists[j['course code']][j['section']] = {'sections':[j['section']],'class list':[i['id']]}
```

https://paiza.io/projects/e/pV2hY_ND0SD7iT0civUNkA?theme=twilight

```
{'UK 60': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'GF 24': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'ME 40': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'VY 44': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'EN 94': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'EQ 61': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'UZ 22': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'KS 36': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'VH 63': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'IW 81': {'C': {'sections': ['C'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'WE 15': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'ZP 68': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'GI 78': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'GK 72': {'C': {'sections': ['C'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'FA 24': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'UJ 28': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}}
```

### Alternative 2:

Instead of always manually assigning an empty dict, use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
class_lists = defaultdict(dict)
```

https://paiza.io/projects/e/TA4p75j9MpZ_5csfL_TWWw?theme=twilight

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'UK 60': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'GF 24': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'ME 40': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'VY 44': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'EN 94': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['201001']}}, 'EQ 61': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'UZ 22': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'KS 36': {'B': {'sections': ['B'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'VH 63': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'IW 81': {'C': {'sections': ['C'], 'class list': ['211002']}}, 'WE 15': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'ZP 68': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'GI 78': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'GK 72': {'C': {'sections': ['C'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'FA 24': {'D': {'sections': ['D'], 'class list': ['201003']}}, 'UJ 28': {'A': {'sections': ['A'], 'class list': ['201003']}}})
```